# Why use spellotape instead of the reparo spell?

Tags: harry-potter

In Chapter 10 of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Ginny mends her schoolbook with Spellotape:

> "Why are they all sending Howlers?" asked Ginny, who was mending her
>   copy of *One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi* with Spellotape on the
>   rug in front of the living room fire.

Wouldn't it be quicker and cleaner if for example Molly just mended it with the Reparo spell?

Comment: Presumably the same principles apply to book-mending as to clothes mending. If you don't have all the original parts, reparo won't fix the book properly. By comparison, Spellotape will allow you to fix *non-contiguous* pieces without disfiguring the shape of the page.

Comment: Thanks :-). So while reparo would help on some cases or maybe just partially, on the described scene it just wouldn't be enough, right?

Comment: It's pure guesswork, but if her pages weren't just torn, but also missing bits then reparo wouldn't work properly. Think of reparo as magical glue. If you try to glue bits together **that weren't originally touching**, then you'll end up with wonky pages.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate given that there is no mention of repairing books in the other question or any of its answers.